# Ant string functions?

Tags: java, string, ant

Does Ant have any way of doing string uppercase/lowercase/captialize/uncaptialize string manipulations?  I looked at PropertyRegex but I don't believe the last two are possible with that.  Is that anything else?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129672/uppercase-lowercase-capitalize-an-ant-property/7131195#7131195

Answer (score 14):

[From this thread](http://marc.info/?l=ant-user&m=108988637506114&w=2), use an Ant `<script>` task:

```
<target name="capitalize">
    <property name="foo" value="This is a normal line that doesn't say much"/>

    <!-- Using Javascript functions to convert the string -->
    <script language="javascript"> <![CDATA[

        // getting the value
        sentence = project.getProperty("foo");

        // convert to uppercase
        lowercaseValue = sentence.toLowerCase();
        uppercaseValue = sentence.toUpperCase();

        // store the result in a new property
        project.setProperty("allLowerCase",lowercaseValue);
        project.setProperty("allUpperCase",uppercaseValue);

    ]]> </script>

    <!-- Display the values -->
    <echo>allLowerCase=${allLowerCase}</echo>
    <echo>allUpperCase=${allUpperCase}</echo>
</target>
```

Output

```
D:\ant-1.8.0RC1\bin>ant capitalize
Buildfile: D:\ant-1.8.0RC1\bin\build.xml

capitalize:
     [echo] allLowerCase=this is a normal line that doesn't say much
     [echo] allUpperCase=THIS IS A NORMAL LINE THAT DOESN'T SAY MUCH

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

**Update** for WarrenFaith's comment to separate the script into another target and pass a property from the **called target** *back to the calling target*

Use [antcallback](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/antcallback_task.html) from the ant-contrib jar

```
<target name="testCallback">
    <antcallback target="capitalize" return="allUpperCase">
        <param name="param1" value="This is a normal line that doesn't say much"/>
    </antcallback>
    <echo>a = ${allUpperCase}</echo>
</target>
```

and `capitalise` task uses the passed in `param1` thus

```
 <target name="capitalize">

        <property name="foo" value="${param1}"/>
```

Final output

```
   [echo] a = THIS IS A NORMAL LINE THAT DOESN'T SAY MUCH
```

Comment: Though it is easier with Java 6, it works with Java 5, but you have to provide an implementation of your scripting language, e.g., Rhino for Javascript.

Comment: @JoseK: Do you know how I can separate the script in a target? When I do that, the property changed in the target, but afterwards the old value is restored. My problem is, that I want to make the main target as small as possible so that even non-programmer are able to change properties. Thanks

Comment: @Warren: I tried using `antcall` to call the separated script. but properties set by the called targets will not persist back to the calling project, as per the docs. How have you tried?

Comment: @JoseK: Exactly the same way like you. Just `antcall` and the target, which was defined in the same xml. Thought that `project` means for the complete ant run, but it seems thats not the case. If you stumble upon a solution, please share :) Thanks!

Comment: @JoseK: Great! Works perfect!

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood what capitalize means - I'd expect that to only make the first character upper case.

Comment: javascript has been removed from jdk15+, any other ways?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) task and use a jsr223-supported script language like javascript, jruby, jython,... to do your string handling