# converting a string from uppercase to lowercase in ant build.xml

Tags: ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UPPERCASE, lowercase, Capitalize an Ant property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129672/uppercase-lowercase-capitalize-an-ant-property)

Need to convert a string from upper case to lower case in ant build.xml file

var=xxx
Say if i have to make this as XXX and pass it to other variable.
I tried few approaches suggested in the forum but they dint work for me..

Can someone help me on this..

I tried the links below which dint work for me..
[Ant string functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725827/ant-string-functions)
[How do you convert a string to uppercase in ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5941274/how-do-you-convert-a-string-to-uppercase-in-ant)

Am using ant version 1.6.1

Comment: Possible duplicate: [UPPERCASE, lowercase, Capitalize an Ant property](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7129672/1164465)