# UPPERCASE, lowercase, Capitalize an Ant property

Tags: regex, ant

In Ant, I have a property named '`some_property`', and let's say its value is "`hello`".

I'm trying to **replace a place-holder inside a text file** with this property's value ("**hello**") as an **upper-case**.
So, I have this task:

```
<replaceregexp match="SOME_PLACE_HOLDER" replace="${some_property}" byline="true">
```

And I want it to work *as if I would have this task*:

```
<replaceregexp match="SOME_PLACE_HOLDER" replace="HELLO" byline="true">
```

*I wish to avoid external Ant tasks* (such as Ant-Contrib), therefore the ***solution needs to be a pure regex*** - it must be possible!

UPPERCASE, lowercase, and Capitalized.

Anyone knows the correct regexes?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I understand that you want to avoid Ant extensions, but the constraint that the solution be implemented using regex is a little tight - apologies if the following bends (breaks?) that rule too much.

Ant ships with a javascript engine these days, so anything that seems problematic to implement in Ant xml can usually be hidden away in a [`scriptdef`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scriptdef.html).  Below are four that do case changing.

In your case, you would take your `some_property` property and process it through the `upper` script to get an uppercased version of the string to use in the `replaceregexp` task.

```
<scriptdef language="javascript" name="upper">
    <attribute name="string" /> 
    <attribute name="to" />

    project.setProperty( attributes.get( "to" ),
                         attributes.get( "string" ).toUpperCase() );
</scriptdef>

<scriptdef language="javascript" name="lower">
    <attribute name="string" /> 
    <attribute name="to" />

    project.setProperty( attributes.get( "to" ),
                         attributes.get( "string" ).toLowerCase() );
</scriptdef>

<scriptdef language="javascript" name="ucfirst">
    <attribute name="string" /> 
    <attribute name="to" />

    var the_string = attributes.get( "string" );
    project.setProperty( attributes.get( "to" ),
                the_string.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + the_string.substr(1) );
</scriptdef>

<scriptdef language="javascript" name="capitalize">
    <attribute name="string" />
    <attribute name="to" />

    var s = new String( attributes.get( "string" ) );
    project.setProperty( attributes.get( "to" ),
            s.toLowerCase().replace( /^.|\s\S/g,
            function(a) { return a.toUpperCase(); }) );
</scriptdef>
```

Example use:

```
<property name="phrase" value="the quick brown FOX jUmped oVer the laZy DOG" />

<upper string="${phrase}" to="upper" />
<lower string="${phrase}" to="lower" />
<ucfirst string="${phrase}" to="ucfirst" />
<capitalize string="${phrase}" to="capitalize" />

<echo message="upper( ${phrase} )${line.separator}= '${upper}'" />
<echo message="lower( ${phrase} )${line.separator}= '${lower}'" />
<echo message="ucfirst( ${phrase} )${line.separator}= '${ucfirst}'" />
<echo message="capitalize( ${phrase} )${line.separator}= '${capitalize}'" />
```

And output:

```
[echo] upper( the quick brown FOX jUmped oVer the laZy DOG )
[echo] = 'THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPED OVER THE LAZY DOG'
[echo] lower( the quick brown FOX jUmped oVer the laZy DOG )
[echo] = 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog'
[echo] ucfirst( the quick brown FOX jUmped oVer the laZy DOG )
[echo] = 'The quick brown FOX jUmped oVer the laZy DOG'
[echo] capitalize( the quick brown FOX jUmped oVer the laZy DOG )
[echo] = 'The Quick Brown Fox Jumped Over The Lazy Dog'
```

*Thanks to Poni and Marco Demaio for the [implementation of the Capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string/5678673#5678673).*

Comment: Knew about <script> which doesn't seem to support passing of arguments. Anyway, with your answer and the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332811/capitalize-words-in-string I've got what I wanted. So, thanks a lot Martin!

Comment: To use <script>, you either need to be on Java 1.6, or have BSF in Ant's `lib` directory (and BSF requires jakarta commons-logging.jar and Mozilla Rhino js.jar)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to `SCriptdef` and any convenient language.

```
<scriptdef language="javascript" name="upper">
<attribute name="string" /> 
<attribute name="to" />

project.setProperty( attributes.get( "to" ),
                     attributes.get( "string" ).toUpperCase() );
</scriptdef>
```

Here JavaScript is mentioned as an example. You can also use any other.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript in ant has become a bit of a hassle.
This approach might work if you have a Unix shell available:

```
  <exec dir="."
      executable="/usr/bin/tr"
      os="Mac OS X"
      inputstring="${ant.project.name}"
      outputproperty="ant.project.name.lower"
      >
    <arg value="[:upper:]"/>
    <arg value="[:lower:]"/>
  </exec>
```

Substitute or add OS names as appropriate. I'm not sure if `tr` can capitalize, but case conversion is easy.